# Problem facing $\int_{0}^{1}\ln({1-\sin x})\mathrm dx=\ln 2+\ln \pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln({1-\sin x})\mathrm dx=\ln 2+\ln \pi$$

How may one show that?

I have try the following but it is not working.

using sub: $u=1-\sin x$

$$\int_{1}^{1-\sin 1}{\ln u\over u(2-u)}\mathrm du$$

$${2\over \ln 2}\int_{1}^{1-\sin 1}\left({1\over u}+{1\over 2-u}\right)\mathrm du$$

$${\ln 2\over 2}\ln\left({u\over 2-u}\right)$$

Comment: For $x\in(0,1]$, $1-\sin x<1$ and hence $\ln(1-\sin x)<0$. The integral should be negative.

Comment: Did you forget to add the "following" after telling us "I have try the following but it is not working"...  nothing follows.

Comment: would you show us what you have tried?  would be really helpful

Comment: On Math SE, a question should specify its context, including what you have tried, where the problem comes from, why it is worth thinking about, ... This allows answerers to gauge your level of mathematics and give appropriate guidance and information.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+log(1-sin(x))+from+0+to+1) is your friend. Use it to check if your conjectures are true before trying to prove them

Comment: Your work doesn't hold up wrt substitution.  If $u = 1-\sin x$, then $du = -\cos x dx$, but there is no $- \cos x dx$ in the original problem....

Comment: @amWhy cosx in terms of u is $\,u(2-u)$

Comment: But that evaluates to $\cos^2(x)$. So $-\cos x = -\sqrt{u(2-u)}$ But thanks for your observation.

Comment: Can it be that you are looking for the proof of $$-\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(1-\sin x)dx=\frac{\pi\log 2}{2}+2G,$$ where $G$ is the Catalan constant? There is certainly nothing interesting if the upper integration limit is set to 1.

Answer (score 2):

For $x∈(0,1]$, $1−\sin x<1$ and hence $\ln(1−\sin x)<0$. So, $\displaystyle \int_0^1\ln(1-\sin x)dx\le0$.

Since $\ln 2+\ln \pi>0$. The equality does not hold.